Word, phrase or idiom for reaping the consequences of false belief in being able to control chaotic results
I'm looking for a way to describe the negative results (consequences) of someone having chosen to do something they foolishly thought would protect them from an likely bad result (a chaotic evil person, for example; or a system too complex to predict).  For example, someone thinks they can avoid being bitten by a wild animal by treating it gently but not otherwise taking rational precautions.  Or something like the frog and the scorpion tale.

Reaping the whirlwind is an idiom that is pretty close, but not quite, in that it leans towards the neutral "actions have consequences" instead of the "you should have known better but your hubris made you think you could escape those consequences."
Ride the tiger similarly is close but misses the mark because it implies that if you can hold on, you can eventually get the better of it.  I'm looking for an idiom where the more likely outcome is the tiger eats you.
Voting for face-eating leopards results in your face being eaten pretty much has the tone and nature of what I'm looking for, but focuses purely on voting.

I keep thinking I've seen an idiom that fits perfectly, but I'm drawing a blank.

Answers at the previous post: Playing with fire / sailing close to the wind / dicing with death / ride a tiger / flirting with disaster / tickling the dragon's tail / fly too close to the sun / poking the bear / Mess with the bull you get the horns: at no point are you in control, of either bull [or lion] / skating on thin ice / dancing with the devil / tempting fate.

@EdwinAshworth  Those are a bunch of good ideas.  I'd love to vote them up as answers.  Thanks.

Maybe too memey; 'I didn't want leopards to eat ANYONE'S face,' sobs woman who voted for the Leopards Eating People's Faces Party.wiki.

"Play stupid games, win stupid prizes" might be what you're looking for. It refers to someone doing something widely regarded as very stupid, with the belief that they can somehow defy the odds and do it successfully or unharmed. Ultimately, things usually don't go as they expect, and they win a "stupid prize", typically in the form of injury or property damage. The bad outcome of the person's actions is utterly unsurprising to most people.
This doesn't quite capture the notion of a false belief underlying the person's overestimation of their abilities, it could be simply that they just haven't thought about it much at all. Most reasonable people would classify the action in question as "stupid", though, which suggests the person doing it must have some reason for doing so (whether that's inattention or misplaced confidence).
An example of an applicable scenario might be someone trying to show off by breaking a bottle over their own head. When they instead knock themselves unconscious, no one is surprised, and it's an examples of someone playing a stupid game and winning a stupid prize. Another example might be deliberately antagonizing (or even simply closely approaching) a wild animal, and getting attacked by it as a result.

There is the idiom

If you play with fire, you get burned.

Though it is commonly a warning for future danger caused by foolishness of the kind you describe, it can also refer to negative outcomes of past actions, as we can see in the example provided by Farlex Dictionary of Idioms cited by Freedict.com. The idiom is:

A warning that dangerous or risky actions often lead to pain and injury.

It's no surprise that Jeff ended up in jail after getting involved in that counterfeiting scheme. If you play with fire, you get burned.


Also flirting with danger comes to mind but it refers less to the negative outcome than to the actual folly of venturing to be over-confident in situations where prudence is advisable.

Hoist by [one's] own petard
A bomb-maker believes that his knowledge and skill will protect him during the course of his work.  But bomb-making is inherently dangerous, and bad luck can result in very bad consequences very quickly, regardless of one's knowledge or skill.
Sometimes chaos / bad luck results in a bomb-maker being hoist (blown up) by his own petard (bomb).
This phrase, originally in Hamlet, has become proverbial.

"Fly too close to the sun"

To become overly ambitious or greedy; to overreach oneself; to reach for something unattainable or unachievable.

Icarus was warned to not attempt it and the phrase encompasses recklessness and ignoring limitations.

One proverb (from Phrase Finder) is

a little knowledge is a dangerous thing
The proverb ‘A little knowledge is a dangerous thing’ expresses the idea that a small amount of knowledge can mislead people into thinking that they are more expert than they really are, which can lead to mistakes being made.

The saying is attributed to Alexander Pope's An Essay on Criticism, 1709 although it may have been used earlier. Obviously, the idea itself wasn't new.

Although this is not a general answer for all of the cases you mentioned, in the specific case of keeping company with people who have a bad track record, you can consider If you lie down with dogs, you will get up with fleas.
"He that lieth down with dogs shall rise up with fleas" has been attributed to Benjamin Franklin's Poor Richard's Almanack, according to Wikipedia.
It is usually accepted (per the same Wikipedia article) to mean that "You should be careful of the company that you keep, since

Associating with those of low reputation may not only lower your own but also lead you astray by the faulty assumptions, premises and data of the unscrupulous."


You might consider the phrase feeding the crocodile, although it's not a widely recognized idiom/metaphor in the traditional sense. The phrase originates from a famous quote by Winston Churchill:

An appeaser is one who feeds a crocodile, hoping it will eat him last.

While it's not a common idiom, it is often used as an allusion to capture the nuance of thinking you're protecting yourself by trying to appease a dangerous or chaotic force, only for it to backfire. The imagery of "feeding the crocodile" suggests that, rather than offering safety, the act of appeasing simply delays the inevitable outcome.

Thank you!  I had not heard this idiom before, but it comes very close to what I was thinking.

In the light of recent events the word you might be seeking could be Trumped
Here the choatic consequences will hold the winning hand. :)
More generally the question implies an element of "magical thinking" on the part of the person believing they can control the chaos around them which also contains slivers of hubris, narcissism, and cognitive dissonance.
Clearly this a reasonably common affliction but sadly there doesn't appear to a precise term for this malady.

You seem to be looking for something a bit less crude, but a popular acronym is FAFO for "Fuck Around (and) Find Out", which received a nomination for 2023 ACRONYM/INITIALISM OF THE YEAR (ad-hoc category) by the American Dialect Society.
"We are now reaching the "Find Out" phase of FAFO".
Some information on the alleged origins here.

Earlier, this was "poke it with a pointy stick and find out" - " As in the Indian parable of the blind men touching an elephant, everyone comes with their own emotional history, temperament and background, which all but guarantees they will each perceive a different animal. The only certainty, Adam said, is that it’s likely a mistake to poke it with a pointy stick." https://business.rice.edu/wisdom/peer-reviewed-research/anger-in-negotiations

It's not a standard idiom, but I like "They didn't think their cunning plan all the way through."
(I may be heavily influenced by the TV series "Blackadder".)

This expression may be more general than you are looking for, but it's common:

You made your bed, now lie in it.

Meaning, "You need to deal with the consequences of a situation you created."  It's used not just for foolish actions, but also when selfish, short-sighted, or mean-spirited actions come back to bite you.
See: https://english-grammar-lessons.com/you-made-your-bed-now-lie-in-it-meaning/
Come to think of it...

Come back to bite you

...matches the "being bitten by a wild animal" example in the original question.  See
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+back+to+bite+you

Put (one's) head in a lion's mouth
Literally, a lion trainer (not tamer) or one's assistant putting their head in a lion's mouth to demonstrate control and trust, and bravery as well, for all to see.
Assistant positon open: No prior experience required. Apply at three-ring circus, lion's den. Bring courage and change of clothes.
Origin of Put one’s head in the lion’s mouth

Put oneself in a potentially dangerous situation or face up to something bravely, derives from circus
lion-tamers’ practice of literally putting their heads into the mouths of lions to illustrate their trust
and control over their lions.
Idiom Origins


A single word that expresses the mistaken idea of thinking you will be in control of a situation is

folly
the condition of being foolish, or a foolish action or belief:
It would be folly to attempt a trip in this snowstorm.

From Cambridge Dictionary.
